# How can I use xpath not operator in APPIUM

Tags: xpath, appium, operator-keyword, except

I tested these two XPath expressions:

```
//*[not(@class='android.view.ViewGroup[2]')]
```

and

```
//*[not(contains(@class,'android.view.ViewGroup[2]'))]
```

But that syntax doesn't work. I want to filter unavailable days with not or another operator. But I can't. Thanks for help

Comment: Please describe your requirements more clearly. At the very least, show some XML input and indicate what you want to select. Do be aware that both your expressions will select every element that doesn't have a `class` attribute (plus some others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
//*[not(@class='android.view.ViewGroup')][2]
```

or, an easier version:

```
//*[@class!='android.view.ViewGroup'][2]
```

Both select the second matching element with the given condition.

Comment: Wow, that's a wild guess as to the intent. But who knows, it might be a correct one!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried both of them but unfourtunately they didn't work my side. 

**_android.view.ViewGroup[2]_** unavailable date syntax is like that. Because of that I used **[2]** downside.

//android.widget.HorizontalScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup//*[@class!='android.view.ViewGroup[2]']

//android.widget.HorizontalScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup

Both of the is showed same result.